# --chakra-fontSizes-5xl is not defined

Tags: node.js, next.js, chakra-ui

I'm building a simple landing page with NextJS and ChakraUI. In my localhost, everything seems okay (both `npm run dev` and `npm run start` execution). But when I upload the build to production server, some styles don't apply correctly. For example, the browser does not recognize the style `font-size: var(--chakra-fontSizes-5xl);` saying that `--chakra-fontSizes-5xl is not defined`.

[image]

I look for other CSS variables, and turns out that all variables with camelcase format converted into lowercase format, this is different from what is described in the [documentation](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/css-variables).
[image].

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting to my hosting service provider, it turns out that they use web server-side caching using PageSpeed Cache and NGINX Cache.

The solution they proposed was to disable the features (or enable Bypass cache menu for NGINX Cache).

After doing that, my site works fine.